# Route53 subdomain alias for S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, static-site

I am trying to static webpage from S3 bucket.

Created S3 bucket `test.dev.mydomain.com` with following policy

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test.dev.mydomain.com/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

After this I was able to access the `http://test.dev.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Now I want to create DNS record under `mydomain.com` in route53. I tried to create following alias in Route53

**Name :** `test.dev.mydomain.com`
**Type :** `A - IPv4 address`(Tried `CNAME` too)
**Alias :** `Yes`
**Alias Target :** `test.dev.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`

but getting 
**- Alias Target contains an invalid value.** while saving the record.

**Update** after John Rotenstein's answer :

Was able to select the bucket from the list after waiting more than 10 min and save the record.

Able to access `http://test.dev.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`

But still `test.dev.mydomain.com` giving `404 page not found`

**Update** :

Recent finding is `test.dev.mydomain.com` works only in firefox, not any other browser.

Comment: did you try using cloudfront for serving your website ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work as follows:

- Created an Amazon S3 bucket in the ap-southeast-2 region
- Activated Static Website Sharing
- Created a Record Set in Route 53 with:

  - DNS name that matches the bucket name
  - Type: A
  - Alias: Yes
  - Alias Target: Selected bucket from list

**Note:** It took a long time (10 minutes?) before the bucket appeared in the list!

The format was:

- Bucket name: `foo.domain.com`
- Alias Target: `s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`

Note that the target **does not contain the bucket name!** This is because the DNS name will resolve to S3, which will then use the full DNS name to determine the bucket name.

Comment: This is actually because the DNS name will resolve to a generic regional S3 endpoint, which will then use *the HTTP `Host` header* sent by the browser to determine the bucket name.  The original name in the query to Route 53 isn't preserved at the DNS layer.

Comment: Updated my my question.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome & Safari redirect all http to https and because of this `http://test.dev.mydomain.com` not working in Chrome & Safari. But `http://test.dev.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com` was working.

I fixed this by adding CloudFront to this sub/domain and everything works on `https`